# if facebook app not installed , login popup webview comes twice

Tags: android, android-intent, android-facebook

I have integrated login with facebook in my app. When the app is installed , it asks me the permission twice and logged me in to my application(this is the expected behavior).

When I delete my facebook application, It opens a webview popup to login with my username and password two times.After second time login it shows a message saying

How do I make the login webview pop up come only once? without any error messages when the facebook app is not installed.

> Error Message "The page you requested cannot be displayed right now and it may be temporarily unavailable ...".

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
                        @Override
                        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(
                                AccessToken oldAccessToken,
                                final AccessToken currentAccessToken) {
                            this.stopTracking();
                            if(currentAccessToken != null) {
                                GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                        currentAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
                                        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onCompleted(
                                                    JSONObject jsonObject,
                                                    GraphResponse response) {
                                                try {
                                                    email = jsonObject.getString("email");
                                                    gender = jsonObject.getString("gender");
                                                    id = jsonObject.getString("id");
                                                    name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                                                    if (mAuthTask == null && (!email.isEmpty()) && (!name.isEmpty()) && (!id.isEmpty()) && (!gender.isEmpty())) {
                                                        SharedPreferenceManager.setPreference("id", id);
                                                        dismissProgressDialog();
                                                        mAuthTask = new UserLoginTask(email, "", name, "facebook", id, currentAccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().getToken(), gender, SharedPreferenceManager.getPreference("registrationid"));
                                                        mAuthTask.execute((Void) null);
                                                    }

                                                } catch (JSONException exe) {

                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
                                parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,link,email,gender");
                                request.setParameters(parameters);
                                request.executeAsync();
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
                }



                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    dismissProgressDialog();
                    if (accessTokenTracker != null) {
                        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
                    }
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    dismissProgressDialog();
                    if (accessTokenTracker != null) {
                        accessTokenTracker.stopTracking();
                    }
                    LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                }
            });
```

Comment: The way your question is formatted at the moment doesn't fit with stack overflow rules and will likely attract a large number of down votes or be closed very quickly. To avoid this, it's a good idea to edit your question to provide clear examples of your overall problem, what issues you're facing, what you have tried, and why those don't work. Also, it's worth searching to see if your question has already been asked before.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question above. Please let me know how to solve the issue

Comment: That's much better. You'll receive a better quality of responses rather than down-votes and an eventual close.